# OneClick install software to automatically install packages like wordpress

Tags: packages, installation, clickonce

All the hosts now have One Click install for packages like Wordpress, Drupal and so on.

Is there oneclick installer software that I can install on my VPS that gives me the ability to have one click installers for these popular packages?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, there is...

Comment: What's with the negative vote?! Invalid question?

Comment: You got a -1 for posting a poorly worded off topic question which doesn't have enough information to be properly answerable. You haven't even bothered to tell us what operating system you're running.

Comment: To @JohnGardeniers point, a "one click" package installation isn't really possible natively on the Windows platform, but if you create an answer file, you can easily launch a unattended or silent installation with a single line from the command prompt.  However, if you create a software advertisement with SCCM, you can push it out to client machines (collections) with one click, and if you set it to be mandatory and install automatically, one click is all you'll need.  Huzzah, one-click deployment of "Wordpress, Drupal, and so on."  :/

Comment: @HopelessN00b, I read the question in the context of web hosting, which allows "oneclick" installation but the underlying software will be different to that used on *nix.

Answer (score 3):

1. Packages provided by your distribution. With Debian/Ubuntu, you can do "apt-get install wordpress", etc. Source Debian Unstable repo if you need to. RPM-based distros will have something very similar. How these distribution-provided webapps are packaged varies, some packages may support virtual hosts and multiple installations, but many of them only support one instance running on the same server.
2. Hosting companies usually use Softaculous (or Fantasico, installatron)  to do this. You can license and install Softaculous yourself. Your VPS hosting company might already have a reseller license for cPanel/Plesk + Softaculous,  which you can install on your VPS for a small monthly fee. Virtual hosts are generally well-supported.  http://www.softaculous.com/softaculous/

   3. You might find Sofaculous AMPPS useful, it's a LAMP dev stack for Windows/OSX with Softaculous one-click installer built-in, so you can test apps easily on your desktop before installing them on your server. http://www.ampps.com/